# JSONの配列から、各行の複数要素を一行ずつ取得したい

Tags: json

次のようなJSONがあります。

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "address"  : {
    "streetAddress": "naist street",
    "city"         : "Nara",
    "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type"  : "iPhone",
      "number": "0123-4567-8888"
    },
    {
      "type"  : "home",
      "number": "0123-4567-8910"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### 行いたいこと

次のような結果、配列の各要素中の複数項目の値を一行ずつ出力するJSONPathはないでしょうか？

```
[
  iPhone,0123-4567-8888
  home,0123-4567-88910
]
```

#### 試したこと

次のようなJSONPathを用いましたが、結果は項目毎で1行となり、期待した結果は得られませんでした。

・試行したJSONPath

```
$.phoneNumbers[*].[type,number]
```

・結果

```
[
  "iPhone",
  "0123-4567-8888",
  "home",
  "0123-4567-8910"
]
```

JSON中の配列要素に対する、繰り返し処理の記述が必要なのではないか、と考えておりますが、その方法がわからずにおります。
どなたかご教示いただけますと幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: こちらは、実際に JSON を取得したい環境(言語など)は何になりますでしょうか? 例えば、サーバー上であるならば `jq` を使うのが良い、となりますし、 javascript 関数で実装するならば、普通に loop を記述すれば良くなります。また、 JSONPath だけでどうしてもやりたく、 JSONPath の仕様としてこれが可能かどうか、というのもまた質問者さんの聞きたいことの可能性があると思っています。ですので、これらのうちどのケースなのか、を質問に追記していただけますでしょうか?

Answer (score 0):

これでいかがでしょうか？

```js
//dataに格納しておきます。
data = {
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "address"  : {
    "streetAddress": "naist street",
    "city"         : "Nara",
    "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type"  : "iPhone",
      "number": "0123-4567-8888"
    },
    {
      "type"  : "home",
      "number": "0123-4567-8910"
    }
  ]
}

// dataから、phoneNumbersのみを選びます。
source = data.phoneNumbers;

// 要素ごとにループさせます。
for(var value of source){
    // value.type value.numberで取り出せます。
    // 一回のループで、iPhoneとその番号。もう一回で、次のデータです。
    document.write("<span>" + value.type + "</span> : <span>" + value.number + "</span><br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ご回答ありがとうございます。

今回はJavaから呼び出すスクリプトエンジン上のJavaScriptでの実行になります。

よって、jqやその他JSONPath用のライブラリ利用は不可となります。

また、JSONPathとして渡せる文字列は一つだけという実装要件があり、ループ文にも対応しておりません。

配列の要素毎に、複数項目を一行で取得する（行いたいことに記載したような形での取得）、JSONPathの記述方法があれば、と考えております。

おそらくは何らかのループなり一旦取得した結果の加工処理を挟まないと無理ではないか、と考えておりますが、もし可能なら一行／一発で取得できる記述方法があれば、ご教示お願いいたします。

Comment: こちらは質問を補足する内容になるので、質問文を編集して追記してください。 / 質問時とは別アカウントになっているようなので、ヘルプを参考にアカウントのマージを検討してください。 - [間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)